# Cannot run MySQL - ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu. I did not set any password to my root account during the MySQL installation process. I am trying to run MySQL with

```
mysql -u root
```

However, I can't, ending up with the following access denied error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then, I thought it might be due to the password issue. I tried this and enter an empty password and hit the Enter key.

```
abc@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then, I even tried entering a password (my user password on the computer). I ended up with this

```
abc@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have seen some solutions, but most of them require to run MySQL first in order to resolve the issue. However, I find myself not able to do anything, stuck here.

Comment: This might lead you in the right direction. http://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin

Comment: @sealz Thanks for directing me there. As a newbie in all these things, I am not sure whether my problem is related to phpmyadmin. Anyways, I tried it and got `abc@ubuntu:~$ mysql -h localhost -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Few other answers mention a config file and reconfiguration steps. I don't know enough about this to provide an in depth response. Hopefully this leads you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: @sealz Thanks a lot. The awkward thing is I cannot open the directory of the folder mysql. So I cannot do anything to the pid file. I am indeed the admin of the computer. So weird.

Comment: did you try `sudo service mysql start` ?

Comment: or you need to reset your password because you can have issues like that lamp if you didnt set your password to anything so for that you need to follow the instruction [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) and let me know if it works or not !

Answer (score 0):

You must login from root so for this you must write sudo like:

```
sudo mysql -p
```

First give your system password

then it asking for mysql server password, in my case '123'
Then you acces your database.

Comment: I am sorry but it is still the same thing. ;(

Comment: Should I type this in a browser? I am sorry but I am even new to Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry , with the time you will learn. Yes , type in browser please.

Comment: I am on Firefox. I got this `Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.`

Comment: I was followed the instruction on [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) and it's work fine. It may work for you.


  [1]:

Comment: This is not related to the browser. You are configuring a mysql server not a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks ok. It looks like you need to reset the root password
[Resetting MySQL root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338015/resetting-mysql-root-password)

Comment: I tried, but encountered another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997789/mysql-folder-inaccessible-on-ubuntu