# mysql folder inaccessible on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, permissions, admin

I am trying to reset my MySQL root password following [the official reference here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

In step #2, I have to do the following

> Locate the .pid file that contains the server's process ID. The exact
>   location and name of this file depend on your distribution, host name,
>   and configuration. Common locations are /var/lib/mysql/,
>   /var/run/mysqld/, and /usr/local/mysql/data/. Generally, the file name
>   has an extension of .pid and begins with either mysqld or your
>   system's host name.

So I go to /var/lib/ and find the mysql folder. I double-clicked it, I got the following pop-up window:

> ## The folder contents could not be displayed.
>
> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "mysql".

I am pretty sure that I am indeed the system admin. Why is it like so and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Start with working with the terminal/console as a root user.
Not a system expert - but it should get you somewhere:
Get into the ubuntu terminal/console
switch to the root user (sudo bash)
Then follow this one :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: Could you please kindly elaborate this to the newbie, i.e. me? Thanks!