# Updated Password Without Hashing it and Occurred a Dead end in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I ran this: `mysql> update user set User = 'alic' and password = 'X' where User = 'r
oot';`

and the output is: `Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 3`

I Tried to login in PHPMYADMIN with usernme = 'root' and password = ''
I got logged in but the problem is I do not have privileges to anything, nor table, nor making a new account, nor Flushing Privileges!

Everytime I try to update the user table I get `Access Denied for ''@'Localhost'`
or `ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table`

if you look closely `''@''localhost;`
meaning that there's an empty username `''`

Also when I try to change my password via PHPMYADMIN
this message pops up `#1133 - Can't find any matching row in the user table`

[image]

Comment: You just said you changed the `root` userids user field to `alic` **so why are you trying to use `root` still** _GET A GRIP_

Comment: I just tried something similiar _Not changing anything as important as `root` of course_ and it kinda screws up the `user` column of the User table. It might be simpler to just uninstall and reinstall in order to get MySQL back into a sensible condition.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm currently using WAMP, if I uninstall it wouldn't the SQL data get cleaned?

Comment: Well yes, but I assume you have screwed the pooch anyway as you can no longer access MySQL anyway as you naffed up the `root` userid **The Super User** If possible do backups and backup your site code also.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm reading this correctly, the MySQL statement you ran renamed all of your `root` account usernames to `alic` with password `X`, but X is not hashed so basically you can't log in as those users because the password will never match.

Then you tried to log in as root, which gave you no privileges -- because you're logged in as the anonymous user, since root doesn't exist anymore.

The solution is the same as if you'd forgotten your MySQL password, which is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401963/2385479 or [Resetting MySQL root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338015/resetting-mysql-root-password). On *nix systems, start MySQL with --skip-grant-tables and set the password again through the command line client, though you'll want to substitute `alic` where the instructions say to use `root`. It does appear as if you're using Windows, and the detailed instructions for all systems can be found in the MySQL manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Summarized Windows instructions:

1. Stop MySQL from the Services control panel
2. Create a text file containing a variation of `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
3. Start the server from the command line as such: `C:\> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt` referencing the actual path to the file you created above.

Again, substitute where appropriate the username `alic` instead of `root`, your desired new password, and path to the text file from step 2.

Once you have a working password for `alic`, you can log back in and rename the three `alic` users to `root.

Answer (score 0):

Isaac reminded me of that possibility, heres how to do it using WAMPServer on Windows.

**How To Reset The `root` users password.**

Stop the mysql service

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
```

Edit the my.ini file

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Find the [wampmysqld] section in the ini file

Add this line directly after the section [wampmysqld] or [wampmysqld64] depending if you installe WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit.

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Restart the mysql service.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Open the MySQL console

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
```

Now we are going to reset the password for the root user, of course this could be used to reset any users password.

enter the following 2 commands at the `mysql>` command prompt, each with a semi colon at the end of a line, and press ENTER after each line to issue the command to mysql.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Or in your case :

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE user='alic';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

*Note that the update should report that it has updated more than one row, that because there are actually 3 user accounts with the userid of 'root' each with a different domain i.e. 127.0.0.1, localhost and ::1*

Now enter 'quit' at the mysql command promt to exist mysql.

Stop the mysql service

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
```

Edit the my.ini file

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Find the [wampmysqld] section in the ini file

```
Remove the 'skip-grant-tables' parameter we added earlier.
**DO NOT Leave this parameter in the ini file its a HUGH security hole.**
```

Restart the mysql service.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

You should now be able to login with phpmyadmin using the userid 'root' and the new password you have just set for that user.

Comment: Well I guess your original change has just totally broken MySQL. I think you should consider uninstalling WAMPServer, deleting the \wamp folder completely(the uninstall leaves a few files ) and then install it again.