# My password root caused disappearance in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, root

I set a password for the user `root` manually in the phpmyadmin, and suddenly the mysql database disappeared from the list.
When I use the control console, the root user can connect without a password, but the command line `show database` doesn't display the mysql database.

Comment: You probably have the wrong permissions for the root user on the host you've logged in from. Try to login from the localhost if you can and see http://en.kioskea.net/faq/673-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost

Comment: I still have the same issue. When I use the mysql console, I can connect on it as root without password but I have the access denied to the mysql database. Via phpMyadmin I don't have the users part to do some updates or changes on tables . the unic DB I can see in phpmyadmin is information_schema.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin on the home page, do you see "User: root@localhost" ? Because there can be many "root" users (each related to one host definition).

Comment: @Marc yes I can see it at right.

Comment: Well I agree with @NeilSmithline that your root@localhost user lacks privileges. If you control your MySQL server, see this hint: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=root%20password#i-have-lost-my-mysql-root-password-what-can-i-do

Comment: @Marc yes but it doesn't work, when I use the console and want to update de privileges for root I'have this error message : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) or ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privileges for this operation.

Comment: @java2dev If you have followed the hint and restarted the MySQL server without security, you won't have an Access denied message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting MySQL root password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338015/resetting-mysql-root-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it after 3 weeks ooof.

1. Shutdown the mysql service
2. Open the my.ini file
3. You have to edit it where is [mysqld] and put skip-grant-tables
4. Save the file and restart the service.

Comment: Well, you followed my advice giving in the comments above. Please mark the below answer as the correct answer. Note that this is a temporary solution while you adjust your password and/or privileges.

Comment: @Marc My issue was the password put for all privilege users. Now I've gave the password only for "root@localhost", and the same one in config.inc.php.

Answer (score 1):

If you control your MySQL server, you can temporarily restart it without security. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=root%20password#i-have-lost-my-mysql-root-password-what-can-i-do