# How can to set users, passwords and privileges for my MySQL database after resetting passwords?

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL 5.7.25 installed in Amazon Ec2.
I have been accessing the Db via ssh into Ec2 and then connect to `MySQL -u root -p` 
While creating a new user (non-root) I messed up with "identified by " clause for the new user.

From then on, I was not at all able to login. So then followed articles in Stackoverflow and tried
a) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432921/3705478
b) [MySql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42742075/3705478)

But still, I was facing issues. 
issues now I'm facing.

1) I had to add `skip-grant-tables` in my.cnf as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407011/3705478 
Otherwise, if I login using MySQL -u root, I don't see my databases. I see only

```
information_schema |
| mysql
```

2) How can I set proper privileges to user + localhost now and remove `skip-grant-tables` ?

Comment: [follow the official documents\](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: looks like you've logged in with an anonymous user. Look at `SELECT CURRENT_USER()`

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I do select current_user() - ```skip-grants user@skip-grants host ```

Comment: how odd. How does 'skip-grants' come in the output of `select current_user()`