# Can't connect sequel pro with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sequelpro

I downloaded and installed mysql community server GPL version 5.7.13 on my Mac OSX El Capitan. Then I downloaded sequel pro. I tried to connect mysql using socket. I used the name `localhost` and username `root` and kept the password blank. When I tried to connect every time I got the message in the picture.

[image]

I also want to add, when I install mysql for the first time, there is a popup which gives me a cryptic password for the `root@localhost`. So instead of keeping the password section blank, I tried that password too. But it kept showing me the same message except `'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surely your root password is not really blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Sequel Pro and connect without password to a localhost server via socket, without any problems. The most likely problem is you typed in the wrong root password. You can [reset the root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338015/resetting-mysql-root-password).

Comment: Looks like there's problem with sequel pro. When I tested the connection, it failed with "Password incorrect". When I connected, it connected successfully. I'm using Sequel Pro 1.1.2

Answer (score 9):

Start mysql server in terminal by:

> mysql.server start

Access in mysql with your root user (deffault user created when installed mysql)

> mysql -uroot

Create a new account by:

> CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

Give it all privileges:

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'new_user'@'localhost';

Then to reload newly assigned permissions run:

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Now you should be able to connect with Sequel Pro with new user:

**Standard**

- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Username: new_user
- Password: new_password

Comment: Followed this word for word, and it still didn't work. I'm using Catalina 10.15.5 with Sequel Pro 1.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure MySQL is running (start MAMP/XAMP servers)
2. MAMP uses "root" for the username AND "root" for the password

Answer (score 0):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost'.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall it and again install. Give the root password at the time of installation. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to restart mysql after changing password, password can be and is in many cases blank, empty carriage return.

the easiest way to restart mysql I have found is by command line

```
mysql restart;
```